# How to concatenate regular expressions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

This is **not** what I'm asking for:

[concatenate multiple regexes into one regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680446/concatenate-multiple-regexes-into-one-regex/680454)

Is there a way to append a regex into another one **(in JavaScript language)** ?

The reason for doing so is to simplify code maintenance (e.g. if the included string is long or easier to maintain by a non-programmer).

In Python, for example, i'd write something like:

```
regstr1 = 'dogs|cats|mice'
regstr_container = '^animal: (cows|sheep|%s|zebra)$' % regstr1
re.compile(regstr_container)
```

however, in JavaScript, the regular expression is not a string.

```
re = /^animal: (rami|shmulik|dudu)$/;
```

or am I missing something?

Comment: i've closed this question; but didn't delete it so others that use the keywords i've used will reach this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185510/how-can-i-concatenate-regex-literals-in-javascript

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use the literal notation. You could instead create a new RegExp object.

```
var myRegex = new RegExp("^animal: (rami|shmulik|dudu)$");
```

Comment: +1, and you can make a placeholder: container = "...(cows|sheep|{BLAH}|zebra).."; var re = new Regexp(container.replace("{BLAH}", regstr1);

Answer (score 3):

```
var regstr1 = 'dogs|cats|mice',
regstr_container = '^animal: (cows|sheep|'+ regstr1 +'|zebra)$',
regex = RegExp(regstr_container);
```